# Connect ipython-notebook via SSH tunnel from a remote location

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to open an ipython-notebook (which is running on a server) on a macbook from a remote location through an ssh tunnel but no data received.
This is the command for the SSH tunnel

```
ssh -L 5558:localhost:5558 -N -t -x  user@remote-host
```

and this is the command I used to lunch the notebook form the server

```
ipython notebook --pylab=inline --port=5558 --ip=* --no-browser --notebook-dir notebooks
```

Than I tried to open it on a new tab with this `remote-host:5558` but no data received.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directive `-L AAAA:somehost:BBBB` will cause SSH to listen on port AAAA on *localhost* (the machine the ssh command is run on) and forward any connection to that port, over the SSH session, to the host somehost port BBBB. So, you need to open `http://localhost:5558/` in the browser on the machine you run the ssh command on.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: [How do I add a kernel on a remote machine in IPython (Jupyter) Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037211/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-on-a-remote-machine-in-ipython-jupyter-notebook)

Remote jupyter kernel/kernels administration utility (the rk) here: https://github.com/korniichuk/rk