# Remote jupyter kernel - different virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I use the package `remote_ikernel` to automatically connect to an azure VM from an azure VM. The two systems are identical, that is, they have the same python environments.

I start a remote kernel using

```
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no {username}@{ip} sudo /anaconda/envs/py36/bin/ipython kernel
```

And then update my local `kernel.json` by filling the parameters in the script below.

```
        {{
    "argv": [
        "/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/python",
        "-m",
        "remote_ikernel",
        "--interface",
        "ssh",
        "--host",
        "{username}@{ip}",
        "--kernel_cmd",
        "/anaconda/envs/{remote_python}/bin/ipython kernel -f {{host_connection_file}}",
        "{{connection_file}}"
    ],
    "display_name": "SSH {username}@{kernel_name}",
    "remote_ikernel_argv": [
        "/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/remote_ikernel",
        "manage",
        "--add",
        "--kernel_cmd=/anaconda/envs/{remote_python}/bin/ipython kernel -f {{connection_file}}",
        "--name=Remote VM",
        "--interface=ssh",
        "--host={username}@{ip}"
    ]
}}
```

**First attempt**
However, we don't want to use the remote `/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/python` but its `py36` brother. I hoped to solve that by adjusting it in the 1st command, but that doesn't solve it. It also didn't help to change any of the `py35` in the kernel.json. How can we achieve that?

**Second attempt (edit)** 
I adapted the `kernel.json` to include the pointer to the `py36` environment. See the updated version above. The log below looks fine, but `import sys; sys.executable` still shows the `py35` version.

```
[I 11:54:57.549 remote_ikernel] Launching kernel over SSH.
[I 11:54:57.549 remote_ikernel] Login command: 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  username@ip'.
[I 11:54:57.889 remote_ikernel] Established connection; starting kernel.
[I 11:54:57.889 remote_ikernel] Current working directory /data/projects/...
[I 11:54:58.040 remote_ikernel] Running kernel command: '/anaconda/envs/py36/bin/ipython kernel -f ./rik_kernel-40d44e0d-4dac-4939-b018-74f4c82b6855.json'.
[I 11:54:59.357 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 40d44e0d-4dac-4939-b018-74f4c82b6855
[I 11:54:59.358 NotebookApp] Restoring connection for 40d44e0d-4dac-4939-b018-74f4c82b6855:d877b8cff59245bf9ca5811d9310ee7f
[I 11:54:59.358 NotebookApp] Replaying 7 buffered messages
[I 11:55:28.382 remote_ikernel] Setting up tunnels on ports: 57033, 45674, 57305, 38105, 56085.
```

With the remote kernel file showing

```
 {
  "shell_port": 45674,
  "iopub_port": 57305,
  "stdin_port": 38105,
  "control_port": 56085,
  "hb_port": 57033,
  "ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "key": "9e336436-...",
  "transport": "tcp",
  "signature_scheme": "hmac-sha256",
  "kernel_name": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `kernel_cmd` is what is run after making the remote connection, so to get the py36 version of ipython on the remote machine, your `kernel.json` should look more like:

```
{
    "argv": [
        "/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/python",
        "-m",
        "remote_ikernel",
        "--interface",
        "ssh",
        "--host",
        "{username}@{ip}",
        "--kernel_cmd",
        "/anaconda/envs/py36/bin/ipython kernel -f {host_connection_file}",
        "{connection_file}"
    ],
    "display_name": "SSH {username}@{kernel_name}",
    "remote_ikernel_argv": [
        "/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/remote_ikernel",
        "manage",
        "--add",
        "--kernel_cmd=/anaconda/envs/py36/bin/ipython kernel -f {connection_file}",
        "--name=Remote VM",
        "--interface=ssh",
        "--host={username}@{ip}"
    ]
}
```

This should be the same as if you invoke `remote_ikernel` with the commandline:

```
remote_ikernel manage --add --kernel_cmd="/anaconda/envs/py36/bin/ipython kernel -f {connection_file}" --name="Remote VM" --interface=ssh --host={username}@{ip}
```

Comment: Hmm I just tried this but when I execute `import sys; print(sys.executable)` I still find myself in the remote `py35` environment.

Comment: Updated my question a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's still relevant but just in case:
Use the `--remote-precmd` option when adding your kernel.
According to the [docs](https://bitbucket.org/tdaff/remote_ikernel/src/default/):

> Command to execute on the remote host before launching the kernel, but
>   after changing to the working directory.

You can use this option to activate your needed env:

```
--remote-precmd=source %PathToVenv%/Scripts/activate
```

I'm using it and it works with remote_ikernel v0.4.6 and my remote is Windows 10.

For Windows, the command would be something like this:

```
--remote-precmd=%PathToVenv%\\Scripts\\activate.bat
```

Comment: When you write "According to the docs" it's good to add link to the section that contains your quotation

Comment: Added a link to the project home