# Run Julia from remote using Jupyter locally

Tags: server, julia, ssh-tunnel, ijulia-notebook

I apologize if it is a trivial question, but I searched and I could not find the answer. My situation is the following:

1. I have access to a server through ssh tunnelling. The server has Julia installed but **not** jupyter.
2. My machine has both, and my code is mostly in jupyter notebooks and I wish to keep it that way.
3. I wish to be able to run my code on a julia kernel on the server, but editing from a Jupyter interface/ IJulia locally.

I have found several guides on how to launch jupyter from remote, but they do not apply since the server does not have jupyter installed. Similarly, I am aware I could convert my code in a julia script and run it, but I would rather keep the convenience of a notebook for editing.

Is this even possible to do?

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: I'm not an expert, you could maybe use git-like version management and sync local / server like that. This way you use jupyter locally. Once the files are synchronized on the server, you run them automatically converting them into scripts something like `jupytext --to notebook --execute notebook.py`, but for julia. Don't forget, if you want graphical interaction with ssh use `-XY` the options.

Comment: this question should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037211/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-on-a-remote-machine-in-ipython-jupyter-notebook

Comment: you will need to install the julia kernel (https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl) on the remote machine though

Comment: In each possible scenario you will need to install IJulia.jl like mentioned above on the remote machine. Once installed you can either (1) use IJulia to launch Jupyter Notebook on the remote machine, setup an SSH tunnel and connect from your local computer or (2) Try to launch just jupyter Julia kernel (using the IJulia installation) launch Jupyter on your local machine and once connected select the remote kernel instead of the local kernel. (1) is easy and natural - is that what you want to do? (2) is trickier but should work as well. In either case you will always need IJulia

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been very helpful. As I get the permission to install IJulia on the server, I'll update the post with the solution.