# Connect to remote iPython notebook

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook, tunnel

**I want to connect to existing notebooks via *ssh tunnel / vpn* on a remote linux machine.**

I can not log in to the remote desktop viewing them,
 but can generally log into another desktop session via *Windows Remote Desktop* (Win7, Linux with xrdp), so that I found the `*.json` files containing the ports (see similar questions **1**, though I have no experience in finding the correct job/file).

After connecting a vpn and putty ssh tunnel (port A), I tried to access `localhost:A` by opening that in Firefox. Also I tried to run `ipython notebook --existing kernel-B.json`.

This did not work.

- Do notebooks have to be on the tunneled port?
- Or is there a way to connect (not start as in **2**), or should I open a tunnel for every notebook port?

---

Similar questions:

1. [Connecting to a remote IPython instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977446/connecting-to-a-remote-ipython-instance)
2. [Connect ipython-notebook via SSH tunnel from a remote location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461734/connect-ipython-notebook-via-ssh-tunnel-from-a-remote-location)

Answer (score 0):

Read this:
[How do I add a kernel on a remote machine in IPython (Jupyter) Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037211/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-on-a-remote-machine-in-ipython-jupyter-notebook)

Remote jupyter kernel/kernels administration utility (the rk) here:
https://github.com/korniichuk/rk

- *Should I open a tunnel for every notebook port?*
- Yes!